# "Runas" in Ant script

Tags: ant, windows-server-2008-r2, runas

I have an application which needs to run with different user name.

I am trying to call "runas.exe" to call the batch file which calls my application.

When I tried this in command prompt it worked fine. One drawback is I have to provide password

I am wondering if this is possible as this runs on build sever without anyone intervention

Here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx Microsoft explains why we cannot give password as command line parameter

I don't know what could be the better approach. Can anyone suggest any good alternative

I use  Windows 2008 R2 64 bit

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98134/how-can-i-make-windows-software-run-as-a-different-user-within-a-script/98323#98323 might help, but CPAU makes no claim about Win 2008.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot use any tools like this. unfortunately

Comment: May be this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783094/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-ant-task-run-as-administrator-in-windows-vista

Comment: Thank you. But i just want to run as different user in domain which is not admin of the machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, unless you write a small program which does this for you. Batch won't cut it for obvious security reasons.

A sample program that will work in windows xp can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WinAutoLogin.aspx).